# What do the option FollowSymLinks and Indexes in .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have following two lines in `.htaccess` file and I just want to know what do they do.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +Indexes
```

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options

Comment: You have searched a lot??? Come on...

Comment: You probably didn't search that much. ;)

Comment: A little comment on the two people so far who voted to close the question: While I agree that it is off topic, I don't see why it should be closed as "not a real question". Though worded a bit differently, still you can easily understand "I want to know what ... does" as a question. However, I'd vote for a close reason "*The OP didn't spend two seconds on finding an answer on his own before spamming SO with a question he could have answered himself with a simple google search...*"

Comment: Actually I wanted to know about this, and the SO indexing on google is placed much higher up than the apache.org docs, and SO, I feel, has more 'human' answers.

Comment: I feel bad about why I asked this.

Comment: To be fair this page is the top result on Google!!!

Answer (score 55, accepted):

`FollowSymLinks` means if a dir is a symbol link, follow the link

`Indexes` means a dir can be show as list if no index page.

Comment: Find out more about symbolic link here. http://www.maxi-pedia.com/FollowSymLinks

Answer (score 26):

`+FollowSymLinks` makes Apache follow system symbolic links (shortcuts, if you would) in your file system.

`+Indexes` allows access to open folders within your file system, e.g. if you forgot to put an `index.{ext_here}` file down within a directory, `+Indexes` would allow list that directory's contents to the user.