# 403 Forbidden on Storage Directory

Tags: laravel, .htaccess

I have a website hosted on Linux with cPanel. I'm able to access all the pages of my website, except for files in my "storage" directory. The file structure is set up with my "public" folder and my main website files ("tbcrp") at the base, and with the "public" folder as the root/default directory. Image of file structure: https://gyazo.com/e1e958f75c92fdc201f2b5975d109f37

Inside in the "public" folder is a symbolic link to a folder in website/storage/app/public. The idea is that this allows for access to the sub-section of storage and is the usual method of access from the documentation:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem#the-public-disk

When I try to access a file at an address like:
**my-domain.com/storage/profiles/homepage-mockup.jpg**

I get a 403 forbidden error.

The .htaccess at the root of my file structure is:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.my-domain.com/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^my-domain.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.my-domain.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !public/
RewriteRule (.*) /public/$1 [L]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Inside my "public" folder, I have another .htaccess file with the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I don't have much experience with access, but the same file structure works locally, so I assume I have a permission configuration error within my website.

Thank you!

Comment: By default storage directory is not accessible on Laravel. That's because it contains sensitive information like logs, encryption keys...

Comment: @EliasSoares Updated my question to include more detail. I'm accessing a sub-section of storage via symbolic link as defined here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem#the-public-disk

Comment: You need to enable followsymlink: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12973592/3429323

Comment: @EliasSoares In this case, is that in the .htacess file within the base directory, or for the "public" folder / webroot?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, after a lot of debugging, including modifying .htaccess but of no use,  i managed to identify the actual problem that caused 403 error.

Solution is simple, in

> Config/Filesystem.php
> where you define your public_path and storage path, you must have same/identical public_path name and storage_path end directory name.

Example:

> 1. Incorrect:

```
public_path('brands') => storage_path('storage/app/public/brandimages');
```

This will generate 403 error, "since public_path('**brands**')" is not same as "storage_path('../../../**brandsimage**')".

> 2. Correct:

```
public_path('brands') => storage_path('storage/app/public/brands');
```

Now the public_path('**brands**') and "storage_path('../../../**brands**')" are same, therefore, correct symlinks will generated,thus solving 403 error.

Generate symlinks with following artisan command

```
php artisan storage:link
```

For relative links, use following

```
php artisan storage:link --relative
```