# How to avoid 500 error from script that is symbolic link

Tags: apache, cgi

I have a perl file in my cgi-bin which works fine when called from a web browser, for example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
foreach $i (keys %ENV) {
  print "$i $ENV{$i}\n";
}
```

However if I create a symbolic link

```
ln -s printenv.pl linkedprintenv.pl
```

I can successfully execute the script from the command prompt, but called from a web browser, I get a 500 internal server error.

How can I get apache to execute the symbolic link without a 500?

Comment: What do the server logs say is the problem?

Comment: **Danger** Some environment variables come directly from the client in CGI; echoing them into an HTML document without any escaping is a serious XSS risk.

Comment: I contacted support for a2hosting and was told I don't have direct access to the server logs since it's a shared server.  I may not be able to update the apache configuration either.  Want to see if there's something I can change within my control, to fix it.  or else, if it requires a server change, I can request that from admin

Comment: You might want to create a `.htaccess` file in that folder and add `+FollowSymLinks` to it. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/12973592/1331451 (first result I found, not exactly the same, but explains the concept).

Comment: It still didn't work after creating .htaccess file containing "Options +FollowSymLinks" ...is there any more information required in that file for it to take effect?

Comment: Is there any information in the error log?

Comment: I don't have access to the logs or the apache.conf file. (shared server)